# OutOfMemoryError due to a huge number of ActiveMQ XATransactionId objects

Tags: java, weblogic, activemq-classic, xa

We have a Weblogic server running several apps. Some of those apps use an ActiveMQ instance which is configured to use the Weblogic XA transaction manager.

Now after about 3 minutes after startup, the JVM triggers an OutOfMemoryError. A heap dump shows that about 85% of all memory is occupied by a LinkedList that contains org.apache.activemq.command.XATransactionId instances. The list is a root object and we are not sure who needs it.

What could cause this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had exactly the same issue on Weblogic 12c and activemq-ra. XATransactionId object instances were created continuously causing server overload.

After more than 2 weeks of debugging, we found that the problem was caused by WebLogic Transaction Manager trying to recover some pending activemq transactions by calling the method recover() which returns the ids of transaction that seems to be not completed and have to be recovered. The call to this method by Weblogic returned always a not null number n (always the same) and that causes the creation of n instance of XATransactionId object.

After some investigations, we found that Weblogic stores by default its Transaction logs TLOG in filesystem and this can be changed to be persisted in DB. We thought that there was a problem in TLOGs being in file system and we tried to change it to DB and it worked ! Now our server runs for more that 2 weeks without any restart and memory is stable because no XATransactionId are created a part from the necessary amount of it ;)

I hope this will help you and keep us informed if it worked for you.

Good luck !

Comment: I'm not with the project anymore, but I think at some point we deleted the tx log, as it was stale for certain, which at the time resolved the issue. Therefore marking as correct.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest it sounds like you're getting a ton of JMS messages and either not consuming them or, if you are, your consumer is not acknowledging the messages if they are not in auto acknowledge mode.

Answer (score 0):

Check your JMS queue backlog. There may be a queue with high backlog, which server is trying to read. These messages may have been corrupted, due to some crash
The best option is to delete the backlog in JMS queue or take a back up in some other queue